# Need to know how to process 1 XML file with 2 XSL files using PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am very new to XSL. I need to process the same XML file with 2 XSL files using PHP SimpleXML. I have tried a few different approaches with no luck.

```
$xmlfile = 'media/xml_files/article.xml';
if (file_exists($xmlfile)) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile) or die("Error: Cannot create object");}
$xslfile = media/xsl_files/jats-html.xsl;
$xsl = simplexml_load_file($xslfile);
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

I need to process the XML with jats-PMCcit.xsl before it goes through the jats-html.xsl transform. Can somebody please point me in the right direction? I can't seem to find an answer online anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`XSLTProcessor::transformToDoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtodoc.php) to process the first transformation and get intermediate transformation result in a `DOMDocument` object type. Then you can pass the `DOMDocument` object to `transformToXML()` to get the final transformation result.